# dos script to find some files , create a folder in the same directory and move them in

Tags: dos

i want to create a dos script (.bat) to search on all sub folders and whenever it finds a file with the word MK11 in the file name it must create a folder named archive and move the file in it.

example:

c:\folder1\folder2\folderX\fileMK11.txt -> c:\folder1\folder2\folderX\archive\fileMK11.txt
c:\folder1\folder3\fMK11ile.txt -> c:\folder1\folder3\archive\fMK11ile.txt

I tried to make the following script from examples i have seen but the problem is that it creates the folder "archive" in the directory where the script is instead of the directory where the file is found.

```
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set /a c=0
    FOR /R %%i in (*MK11*) do (
    set /a c=c+1
    md archive
    move "%%i" archive
    )
    endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this script will get you down the road. I echoed a COPY command rather than a MOVE command, but some of the hard part is done.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\afinder_%RANDOM%_%RANDOM.tmp
DIR /S /B /A-D *MK11* >%TEMPFILE%
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%f IN (`type %TEMPFILE%`) DO (
    ECHO "%%f"
    FOR /F "delims=\ tokens=*" %%a IN ("%%f") DO (
        SET PNAME="%%~pa"
        ECHO PNAME is set to !PNAME!
    ECHO "!PNAME:~-9,7!"
        REM Check to see if this file is already in an Archive directory.
        IF "!PNAME:~-9,7!" == "Archive" (
            echo got one
        ) else (
            echo not one
            IF NOT EXIST "!PNAME!\Archive" (MKDIR "!PNAME!\Archive")
            echo COPY %%f "!PNAME!\Archive"
        )
    )
)
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")
EXIT /B 0
```